issues with react-native-video . initial video buffering getting very slow
We are using react native video player for videos, We are developing an video based application and this player seems to load and buffer a lot. It seems to be very slow. Is this an issue with the package, or can we solve it using some frontend or backend changes?
how to resolve. its frontend or backend

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
